# Python-Finding number of adjacent values in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I'm trying to count how many times there are adjacent values in a list. To simplify, I'll show an example of what I'm looking for below:

I have an input list of 
list= [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] and
I want to output 3 because 2,2,2,2    1,1     and 2,2 are equal adjacent values.
(Zeros are ignored).

Would I be able to solve this using a dictionary?

```
dict={}
list= [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]     

for x in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[x]=0:
         pass
    elif list[x]=list[x-1]:
          dict          #this is the part I'm having trouble implementing
```

Comment: This is part of a bigger problem that I'm facing in a bioinformatics problem. I'm trying to find the number and lengths of contigs in a given sequence, but that's besides the point.

Comment: `list` and `dict` are a poor choice for names, since they shadow the built-in `list()` and `dict()` methods.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't my actual code. I have other variables in the code that may not be understandable like initial_list, coverage, unsequenced_nucs. I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 6):

```
myList = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
import itertools
print sum(1 for key, group in itertools.groupby(myList) if len(list(group)) > 1 and key)
```

**Readable form:**

```
print sum(1
          for key, group in itertools.groupby(myList)
          if len(list(group)) > 1 and key)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

**Edit:** In case, if you don't want to use the above seen method,

```
myList = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
previous, count, result = myList[0], 0, 0
for num in myList[1:]:
    if num == 0: continue
    if previous != num:
        if count:
            result += 1
        previous = num
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
if count: result += 1
print result
```

**Output**

```
3
```

**Edit 1:** As per your request in the comments section,

```
myList = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
import itertools
groupedItems = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(myList) if key]
groupedItemsSizes = [len(item) for item in groupedItems if len(item) > 1]
print len(groupedItemsSizes)             # Number of repeating groups
print float(sum(groupedItemsSizes))/len(groupedItemsSizes)  # Mean
```

**Output**

```
3
2.66666666667
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this code... would there be a way to find the average length of an adjacent sequence using this?


I.E.
2,2,2,2 has length 4, 1,1 has length 2, and 2,2 has length 2 so average length is 2.66.

Comment: @user2812970 yes... but that wasn't your question :)

Comment: Thanks for the second method. That's much more intuitive for a beginner programmer :)

Comment: @user2812970 As Jon says, that was not the original question. I still updated my solution with the question you asked in the comments section. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function that will yield consecutive items and their counts.

```
def count_consequtive_items(lst, exclude=[0], reset_after_pass=True):
    prev = None
    count = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item in exclude:
            if prev and count:
                yield prev, count
            if reset_after_pass:
                prev = None
                count = 0
            continue
        if item != prev and count:
            yield prev, count
            count = 0
        count += 1
        prev = item
    if prev and count:
        yield prev, count
```

Using it:

```
>>> numbers = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]            
>>> list(count_consequtive_items(numbers))
[(2, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Then you can just count how many have a count higher than 1:

```
>>> len([x for x in count_consequtive_items(numbers) if x[1] > 1])
3
```

---

Of course, you could just use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> numbers = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> len([g for g,l in groupby(numbers) if len(list(l)) > 1 and g != 0])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

lst = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

tran_1 =  [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(lst)]

print sum([1 for ele in tran_1 if ele[0] and len(ele) > 1])
```

Comment: isn't @thefourtheye's answer same as yours! you just copy pasted it

Comment: If the concept resembles same as other one, it's doesn't necessarily mean that's copied !!!